# How to copy my file on disk after receive from a socket in C?

Tags: c, printf, fputs

I'm programming a server with C and I send file with my client. I receive the file with my server and i want to write it on disk.
I print it to be sure i had it.
Everything are ok but when i write on disk, it's doesn't write everything.
This is a part of my server code :

```
.
.
.
#define MAX 1024
void whileRead(int *sockfd)
{
    FILE *output = fopen("copy", "w");
    int n;
    char *buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);

    while(1) {
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        //if something in the buffer then print it  
        if(read(*sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)) > 0){
            printf("%s", buff);
            fprintf(output, "%s", buff) // try too with fputs(buff,output)
            if ((strncmp(buff, "exit", 4)) == 0) {
                printf("Client Exit...\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    free(buff);
    fclose(output);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
.
.
.
```

My client :

```
.
.
.
#define SIZE 1024
struct arg_struct {
        SOCKET sock;
        FILE* input;
    };


void *whileWrite(void* arg)
{
    int n;
    char data[SIZE] = {0};
    struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct*)arg;
    while(fgets(data, SIZE, args->input) != NULL) {
        if (send(args->sock, data, sizeof(data), 0) < 0) {
            perror("[-]Error in sending file.");
            exit(1);
        }
        bzero(data, SIZE);
    }
}
.
.
.
```

Do i need to have a bigger buffer ?
Or it's another problem ?
Thank you !

Comment: Likely not the root cause, but you are not verifying the return values from either your call to `fopen` or `malloc` in the server code.  Should _always_ check return values of functions designed to return them.  And here `bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));`  `sizeof(buff)` is only the size of the pointer, not which is probably not what you intend.

Comment: `if(read(*sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)) > 0)` is going to read only 4 (or maybe 8) bytes of data.   `if(read(*sockfd, buff, MAX) > 0)` will read `MAX` bytes.

Comment: but i did     `char *buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);`
So sizeof(buff) as the same size than MAX no ?

Comment: In any case, your code cannot handle general binary fikes that may contain embedded nulls.

Comment: Place this line in your code under where `buff` is created to test the size in bytes: `size_t size = sizeof(buff);` and see what you get.

Comment: In TCP socket code, it's much safer to avoid str* calls, and the like, if you can.  The results returned from calls like read() are rhe ONLY way to be sure how much data has been loaded into/outof buffers.

Comment: So, you do not want, or need, bzero, str*, sprintf or anything like that which relies on, or tries to enfirce, NUL-terminationin buffers.

Comment: ' if ((strncmp(buff, "exit", 4)) == 0' is unreliable.  Each of the five chars may be received by five read calls loading one byte each time.  An extreme example yes, but it could legally happen with TCP byte streaming.

Comment: @Amusing6028 No.  If you did `char *buff = malloc...`, sizeof (buff) is still the size of a `char *`.  It will always be the size of a `char *`, because `buff` will always be a `char *`.